# array printout inside awk has problems

Tags: arrays, awk, printf, counter

I have a script that seems to work: I have a file "insert" which contains

```
+004.1    
-005.2
```

I would like to insert these values when the search pattern criteria is satisfied for each files in my directory. The script below does run, in fact when I echo the part of the array seems fine:

Example (look in the script below):

```
echo ${array1[0]}  prints to +004.2
```

But when I want this to be inserted in the awk (see below in the script):

```
printf( "%s\n",   "       Latitude (N is +)      :  """   '${array1[COUNTER]}' " ", ),
```

it only prints `4.1`, I want this to be printed `"+004.1"`.

Any help is appreciated. For more please look the script below.

```
#**********************************************************************
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
array1=( `cat "insert"`)

for i in *.log
do

    echo  ${array1[COUNTER]} 

    cat $i | awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /Letter/ ) {
                      printf( "%s\n",  "       Latitude (N is +)      :  """   '${array1[COUNTER]}' " ", $0 );
                    } else {
                      print $0;
                    }
                  }' > out$COUNTER

    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1

done
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf()` and a format such as `%+06.1f`.

```
...
printf("%s %+06.1f %s\n", " Latitude (N is +) : ", '${array1[COUNTER]}', $0);
...
```

I've reduced the number of spaces in the string so the line isn't too long for SO.

Since the original code uses `printf("%s\n", ...one string expression...)` and the value in the shell variable is correctly formatted, you can also do the job with:

```
...
print " Latitude (N is +) : '${array1[COUNTER]}' " $0;
...
```

This embeds the string as formatted in the shell into the string that is prefixed to `$0` and uses `print` to output the whole lot.

---

The shell code is eligible for a [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) award.  It can be a good idea to pass variables to `awk` via the command line, too:

```
awk -v latitude=${array1[COUNTER]} \
    '{ if ($0 ~ /Letter/) printf("%s %+06.1f ", " Latitude (N is +) : ", latitude);
       print $0;
     }' $i > out$COUNTER
```

That's a bit more compact and no less legible (to my way of thinking).  The extra information is output if needed before the start of the line, and then the rest of the line is printed unconditionally.  Passing the variable as shown avoids having to break the single quotes in the script.

Also note that the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` must be the first line in the file to have any effect.
The box comment line with all the stars really isn't a lot of help; I'd remove it (them — I already removed the trailing one, but needed to leave the leading one in place to be able to discuss this issue).